# git mergetool output is wrong

Tags: git, github, mergetool

I am new to `git` and trying to get my hands dirty with it.

I cloned my testing repo with single text file at two different folders.
Then i created two branches `B1` in folder1 and `B2` in folder2

In `B1` i added a line, now `test.txt` has following content

```
It is line from dev branch.
It is line from B1.
```

Commited changes in `B1`, merged with `master` and pushed changes back to remote

Now in `B2` also added a different line, it's `test.txt` has following content

```
It is line from dev branch.
It is line from branch 'B2'.
```

When i tried to sync `B2` with upstream `master`, it got merge conflict

```
git pull --rebase origin master

First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Modified test.txt from B2
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       test.txt
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging test.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in test.txt
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
```

I opened mergetool

```
git mergetool
```

It opens meld, but here `Local` and `Remote` files are interchanged.
Local is showing content from `master` branch
Remote is showing content from local `B2` branch. Here is snapshot

https://postimg.org/image/njtivi32d/

Am i looking it wrong or it is actually wrong ?
Can anyone help with it?

Here is mergetool config from `.gitconfig`

```
[merge]
    tool = meld
[mergetool "meld"]
    cmd = meld "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE" --output "$MERGED"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way a rebase works is by rolling back the target branch until reaching the most common ancestor commit between `B2` and `master`, then playing the commits from `master` since that point.  Then, the commits from `B2` occurring *after* that common ancestor commit on the `B2` branch are replayed on top of the `master` commits.

This explains why the local version resembles `master`.  It resembles `master` because this is what the local branch looks like at this point in the rebase.  And the remote looks like `B2` because these commits are being replayed.

It might be easier to understand this with a diagram.  Consider a situation where both `master` and `B2` have diverged by one commit.  This means that since the most recent common ancestor, one commit has been to each branch, respectively:

```
master: ... A -- B -- C
                  \
B2:                D
```

The first step in a rebase is to rewind the `B2` branch and apply the commits in `master` since the commit `B`.  This leaves us with the following:

```
master: ... A -- B -- C
                  \
B2:                C         [D commit not yet reapplied]
```

The last step in the rebase is to *reapply* the `D` commit to `B2`:

```
master: ... A -- B -- C
                  \
B2:                C -- D'
```

This is the point where the merge conflict you saw happened.  At the point, the "local" code you already have is associated with the `C` commit, from `master`, and the "remote" code is actually coming from the original `B2` branch, before the rebase.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. Now it got it. Instead of rebase i tried merge `git pull origin master` followed by `mergertool`, now it is showing content as i expect. Rebase works differently.

Comment: @SamTech Yes, if you directly merge, then you will get the order you might intuitively expect.  I rarely use the merge tools, so I actually don't remember having this question.